# Endpoint redirection in Netlify - Deploy inside a folder

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, netlify, npm-build

I have a built using create-react-app and hosted in Netlify. I created a file called `_redirects` in folder 'public', but it did not work. The redirect is not happening.

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

I tried change the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ....
  "build": "react-scripts build && echo '/* /index.html  200' | cat >build/_redirects ",
  ...
}
```

I tried create a file /netlify.toml on the root (same level as package.json)

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
  force = false
```

I read this stackoverflow question and I tried everything:
[Catch all redirect for create-react-app in netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990467/catch-all-redirect-for-create-react-app-in-netlify)

I think the problem is in the way I am deploying it (because nothing is working) and I tested it in another application that I created a branch for deploy and the file `_redirects` worked perfectly.

[Way I'm deploying on netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agVFI.png) - Image

Page: https://apuro-branch-main.netlify.app/

I'm testing the following direct link: https://apuro-branch-main.netlify.app/login

I tested putting in new branch and all files in the root folder (instead of inside a folder) and it worked.

I think that `(/* /index.html 200)` doesn't work if the deploy is not performed in the root directory (in my case, I did it inside a folder called apuro-frontend/).

So, I've already discovered that all my difficulty is related to the deployment inside a folder (apuro-frontend/). Although I understand the problem now, I still couldn't find a solution for this specific case.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the problem! I believe that the deploy was storing some cache that prevented the correct redirection.

It worked with:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

I had to re-link the deploy (I also tried clearing the cache using the 'Clear cache and retry deploy' command). But it worked even after I did the following steps:

- Go to Deploy Settings
- In the 'Repository' section, select 'Manage repository' , then 'Link to a different repository'.

I selected the same repository I was using and put in the same commands, somehow this time it worked.

This Stack Overflow question helped me: [netlify deploy failed: git ref refs/heads/master does not exist or you do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677269/netlify-deploy-failed-git-ref-refs-heads-master-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-ha)

I had another problem, which I solved following the steps of the best answer and ended up solving both problems at once.