# Netlify deploy failing because of missing git /head ref

Tags: git, github, netlify

I'm not sure how I got into this mess, but netlify is now failing to deploy my deploy previews on PRs. It is not a permissions issue, I've tried linking and unlinking from my repo and even starting fresh PRs after. Here is the netlify deploy log:

```
9:42:31 AM: build-image version: 4c0c1cadee6a31c9bb8d824514030009c4c05c6a (focal)
9:42:31 AM: build-image tag: v4.15.0
9:42:31 AM: buildbot version: b667c0cf0472892d6662aeba3d9a940e2b5df93d
9:42:32 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
9:42:32 AM: Starting to download cache of 214.7MB
9:42:33 AM: Finished downloading cache in 1.664553483s
9:42:33 AM: Starting to extract cache
9:42:35 AM: Finished extracting cache in 1.657643193s
9:42:35 AM: Finished fetching cache in 3.360637578s
9:42:35 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
9:42:35 AM: git ref pull/27/head does not exist or you do not have permission
9:42:35 AM: Creating deploy upload records
9:42:35 AM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
9:42:35 AM: Failed during stage 'preparing repo': git ref pull/27/head does not exist
9:42:36 AM: Finished processing build request in 4.17824995s
```

I've checked my remote refs and found that **pull/27/head** is indeed missing, but **pull/27/merge** does exist. What have I screwed up here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [netlify deploy failed: git ref refs/heads/master does not exist or you do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677269/netlify-deploy-failed-git-ref-refs-heads-master-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-ha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a github outage and had nothing at all to do with my code.